# Jasper Reports - set hyperlink to open other report and transmit collection type parameter

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports, subreport

Can this be done? I have tried but parameter is not transmitted. Only the first selected value appear in generated link and then in the report i am opening when clicking hyperlink, I get null value.

Thanks

jrxml hyperlink code:

```
<textField hyperlinkType="RemotePage" hyperlinkTarget="Blank">
<reportElement uuid="1e57b233-2612-4956-8808-070dc9bcb2f5" x="548" y="30" width="222" height="17"/>
   <textElement textAlignment="Right"><font size="12"/>         </textElement>
   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["RawData >> Click Here"]]></textFieldExpression>
    <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Click to view RawData"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
    <hyperlinkParameter name="_report">
    <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA["repo:/Team_Reports/CIR_RawData"]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
    </hyperlinkParameter>
    <hyperlinkParameter name="Project_Sets2">
    <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Project_Sets}]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
    </hyperlinkParameter>
        </textField>
```

Comment: Show your code. Show your report.

Comment: I only have the jrxml code. will edit the post